# How does the alpha brain wave frequency range distribute over the population?

Tags: eeg

Alpha brain waves show up in your [EEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) when you close your eyes. Alpha waves are brain waves between 8 and 13 Hz.

How does this frequency range distribute over a population of people?

Comment: I don't have the time to give a proper answer right now, but this could be a start: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23551082

Comment: @jona looks promising...

Comment: If there is something wrong with my question, please tell me...

Answer (score 4):

Alpha oscillations vary in frequency within a single subject from brain area to brain area ([Başar, 2012](http://braindynamics.iku.edu.tr/Pdf/A%20review%20of%20alpha%20activity%20in%20integrative%20brain%20function-%20Fundamental%20physiology,%20sensory%20coding,%20cognition%20and%20pathology.pdf)),  likely because there is not a single phenomenon underlying all examples of alpha oscillations.  At this point in time, an answer to this question would be very difficult because we don't even know what alpha oscillations are.

**Reference**

Başar, E. (2012). A review of alpha activity in integrative brain function: fundamental physiology, sensory coding, cognition and pathology. *International Journal of Psychophysiology*, *86*(1), 1-24.

Comment: +1 great link and thanks for your wrap up. I just wonder why nobody ever just made a statistic about that? It seems so simple and (maybe) could be related to other possibly psychological characteristics...